# How to create an array of image objects to use in a FOR loop?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

In my code I open up a bunch of `Image` objects like this:

```
image1 = Image.open(path + '\\my_image_1.png')
image2 = Image.open(path + '\\my_image_2.png')
image3 = Image.open(path + '\\my_image_3.png')
image4 = Image.open(path + '\\my_image_4.png')
image5 = Image.open(path + '\\my_image_5.png')
```

But doing so makes impossible to iterate through the `Image` objects in a `for` loop.

How can I either:
1) create an array of `Image` objects to then be able to use them in a `for` loop? Or if not possible:
2) step through the above images objects in a `for` loop another way?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
images = [Image.open(os.path.join(path, 'my_image_%d.png' % x)) for x in range(1, 6)]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways, the one suggested by Ignacio is probably the most elegant. You could also do something like

```
images = []
images.append(Image.open(path + '\\my_image_1.png'))
images.append(Image.open(path + '\\my_image_2.png'))
```

If you have many images of large size that would take too much memory if opened at once, you might also consider not making an array of images, but array of paths. Then you would open the images individually in the for loop

```
base = "my_path"
paths = [os.path.join(base, 'my_image_%d.png' % x) for x in range(1, 6)]

for path in paths:
    image = Image.open(path)
    # do something with the image
```